# Jquery Load returns [object object]

Tags: javascript, jquery, summernote

I am using Jquery to load my summernote module with text from a text file , however when i execute my function it recognizes the load as an object instead of displaying the text in the document.

How can i get jquery to return the text inside of the file instead of the file as an object.

```
function testing(){

    let word = $('.summernote6').load('http://127.0.0.1:8887/js/summernote/cats.txt');

    $('.summernote6').summernote('insertText', word);
    console.log(word)
}
```

Then console displays `[object object]`

Comment: jQuery's [`.load()`](https://api.jquery.com/load/) function returns the jQuery object that you called `load` on, ie the `$('.summernote6')` object. The contents of the remote resource is inserted into that element once it's loaded

Comment: Read the documentation. `.load()` doesn’t return the loaded contents, it returns a jQuery collection so that you can chain it, like many other jQuery methods. What `.load()` does is that it replaces all the content of all the elements in the collection with the loaded content. This does not seem to be what you want, rather, you want to store it in a variable. To do this you should use `.ajax()`.

Comment: I think you actually want `$.get('http://127.0.0.1:8887/js/summernote/cats.txt').done(word => console.log(word))`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out i just needed to interact with the text content of the object so the below code worked for me.

```
function testing(){

   let word = $('.summernote6').load('http://127.0.0.1:8887/js/summernote/cats.txt');
   let words = word.text();

    $('.summernote6').summernote('insertText', word.text());
    console.log(word.text())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The load method loads a content in an selector.

You can only do:

```
function testing(){
    $('.summernote6').load('http://127.0.0.1:8887/js/summernote/cats.txt');
}
```

It will load the content of **cats.txt** inside the **.summernote6** element

You are getting an **Object** because the variable is receiving the selector with the content already inserted